# Get current value jstl foreach in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl

I want to know how to get the current value in an element of the loop `forEach` in JSTL, my code is :

```
<c:forEach var="mc1" items="${lstMedCon1}">
  <div class="row" style="text-align: center;color:#186793;"> 
    <span id="idEspeciality" class="label label-default" style="background:#186793;font-size: 30px;">${mc1.strEspeciality}</span>
  </div>
</c:forEach>
```

in javascript

```
function goNext() {
   console.log($("#idEspeciality").text());
}
```

In my code the function `goNext()` is called for `setInterval(goNext, 6000)` and for each intervalue the text change in the view, so I want to get the current value in js but the same value is printed in console which is the first value of the list, but in the view the value is changed

Comment: **First**, element ID should be unique within the entire document. So using `id="idEspeciality"` inside `<c:forEach>` is the first problem - this causes `$("#idEspeciality")` to get always the same - first - element generated with the forEach tag. **Second**, you have to to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server, when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser), and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

Comment: Printing the value on setInterval is not the issue. What is the actual issue?

Comment: The issue is that I want to get the idEspeciality value of each iteration, I always get the same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have unique `id` of the tag which value you get. Add a status variable to forEach tag to index IDs.

```
<c:forEach var="mc1" items="${lstMedCon1}" varStatus="stat">
  <div class="row" style="text-align: center;color:#186793;"> 
    <span id="idEspeciality${stat.index}" class="label label-default" style="background:#186793;font-size: 30px;">${mc1.strEspeciality}</span>
  </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Now you can get the value

```
function goNext(index) {
   console.log($("#idEspeciality"+index).text());
}
```

The `index` parameter you can get from ID attribute while inspecting DOM elements generated via `forEach` tag or entering manually.